# How to Make the http Interceptor in flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to know if it is possible to have a global HTTP interceptor for http: ^0.13.4 package to attach token in header for all requests in Flutter or catch error 401 and relogin in one method?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you need a better HTTP Request for handling errors.
Perhaps, you can check [Dio Package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio).

So far as I know, Dio could handle many details about HTTP Request requirements, including attaching tokens to the header.